# send HTML tags in form field on form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, html-helper, form-submit

im trying to submit a form to my controller action, one of the form field contains HTML tags like `<p>`  `<ul>`

i have added

`<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>`

and

`<pages
        validateRequest="false"
</pages>`

in my `web.config`, also

i have added

`[ValidateInput(false)]` to my controller action

but stil when i submit the form when the `description` field contains the HTML tags it gives the following error:

`A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (desc="<ul><li>Comments: Th...").`

what should/could i do, thanks in advance...

i'm using VS 2010, MVC , entity framework

**EDIT**

here is the view side code

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateProductVariant", "home", new { Id = Model.productVariant.ProductVariantId }, FormMethod.Post))
      {%>
    <table>

            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><%: Html.TextArea("ProductVariantName", Model.product.Name)%></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Description:</td>
                <td><%= Html.TextArea("desc",Model.productVariant.Description)%></td>
            </tr>
```

controller side

```
 [ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult UpdateProductVariant(int id, FormCollection collection, bool pub, bool del, decimal hprice)
        {
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Comment: it may be the duplicate of your mention question but the slution proposed in that question doesn't solve my problem...

Comment: Try using **Server.HtmlEncode** for the concerned value

Comment: than I am wrong and your question shall remain open. :)

Comment: I believe all actions in the current request context should have the [ValidateInput(false)] attrib

Comment: @V4Vendetta i have to use an editable field where the user can modify the value and then that value is posted back to controller...

Comment: So if the attribute is set on the relevant part then you should be good to go, still do you use **Html.RenderAction**

Comment: poseted the code... the field `description` is problematic

Comment: Can you try setting the **[AllowHtml]** attrib to the Body Property

Answer (score 3):

The following should work:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            Description = "<p>Hello</p>"
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateProductVariant(MyViewModel model)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

View:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateProductVariant", "home", new { Id = Model.productVariant.ProductVariantId }, FormMethod.Post)) { %>
    <%= Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Description) %>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

You only need to add the `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>` to your web.config if you are running ASP.NET 4.0. Also you don't need to add `<pages validateRequest="false" />`.

If this doesn't work you probably haven't decorated the correct controller action with the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute. This should be the action you are POSTing the form to.

Comment: added the controller side code i am more or less doin the same which you have proposed...

Comment: @3nigma, not exactly. I am using strongly typed view models whereas you are using `FormCollection`. Not sure if this will change something but worth trying. Using view models is a good practice anyways and it works for me.

Comment: that was the only diff in your solution and mine i'm definitely gonna try it... tnx

Comment: nope it works fine if the input doesn't contain html tags... tnx for replying :)

Comment: @3nigma I am not very sure but i think there is a bug associated with the use of FormCollection in MVC maybe needs a patch [Check This](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/14/update-on-asp-net-mvc-3-rc2-and-a-workaround-for-a-bug-in-it.aspx)

Comment: @3nigma Also [See This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022134/mvc-3-rtm-allowhtml-doesnt-work-when-using-formcollection) hope it helps

Comment: @V4Vendetta tnx for the replies, but the bug fixes wont work for me :( something somewhere is not working right ... i'll post the solution if i find it... tnx again